# pair tkinter progress bar with wget download

Tags: python, tkinter, wget

I have a download button when clicked it calls a download function that downloads a video from a media url using wget
example of a video url http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
name = Entry(window, width=10)
name.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)

url = Entry(window, width=10)
url.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
 
dl_button = Button(window, text='download', command=dl) #*********
dl_button.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=W)
 
status_lable = Label(window, text='Ready')
status_lable.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)

bar = Progressbar(window, length=200)
bar.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

the dl function opens up 2 threads one for the download and one for the gui, the gui has a progress bar, that i want to be updated alongside the download:

```
import threading
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import wget
def dl():
    def wg():
        wget.download(
            url.get(), 'C:/Users/Desktop/downloads/'+name.get()+'.mp4')
            
    def update_progress():
        status_lable.config(text='Downloading...')
        # also update the progress bar, based on the progress of the download from wget
        
    dl_thread = threading.Thread(target=wg)
    progress_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_progress)
    dl_thread.start()
    progress_thread.start()
```

is this doable, is it doable with somthing other than wget, or is it simply just not doable?

thx.

Comment: You shouldn't call `tkinter` methods from threads other than the one where you created the `tl.Tk`, otherwise `tkinter` may crash

Comment: but when i execute the '''wgte.download('')''' the gui completely freezes until the download is complete, so is there a work around? i cant find anything similar to what i ma trying to do online, which is weird.

Comment: TheLizzard has pointed out the likely cause of your issue.  Maybe [read this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-thread/)

Comment: I have no issues, I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after along research alot of trial and error, i managed to make it,
here's a demo code:

```
import threading
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import wget
from tkinter import *


def dl():
    def update_progress_bar(block_num, block_size, total_size):
        bar.config(value=block_num, maximum=block_size)
        # when done downloading remove the progress bar
        if block_num == block_size:
            bar.destroy()
            print("Download Complete")

    def wg():
        wget.download('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
                        'C:/Users/..../folder/' + 'koko'+'.mp4', bar= update_progress_bar)

    dl_thread = threading.Thread(target=wg)
    dl_thread.start()


window = Tk()
dl_button = Button(window, text='download', command=dl)
dl_button.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=W)

bar = Progressbar(window, length=200)
bar.grid(column=1, row=2)
window.mainloop()
```

its all about the `bar` *parameter* in `wget`, it takes a function and calles it every **block** of the download, and sends it the full size of the file, the number of **blocks** the full size is divided into, and the current **block** number, then you can update the progress bar for every block inside the called function as shown in the code, good luck all.

**important**:
I've been told in the comments that calling `tkinter` methods from an outside thread may cause the the program to crash, I couldn't find any other solution for this problem online or on my own.
thank you @TheLizzard and @Rory